# Get X and Y of a point rotation a certain distance from another point

Tags: javascript, graph, canvas, rotation, point

I've only found a few solutions searching, and they're either language-specific or too complex. I simply need to get a point n distance from another point rotated n amount. I'm using this for a project in HTML5 canvas. I know that there's a rotate function, but I'm working with paths and I don't believe that works with it. Regardless, I'd just like a formula where I could plug in x, y, distance, and direction.

Comment: Break out the pencil and paper and work out the math. Then turn it into code.

Comment: this is a simple trigonometric calculation. is `"n"` in radians or degrees?

Comment: I used to deal with all these trigonometric calculations way back in the day when developing games. It is fun to do this math when you are programming, even though I used to hate the very same math at college when I had to learn it without knowing where it is applicable. @Ruffian you should go through some math text and learn this stuff, it is interesting and very rewarding once you do it properly and get something to rotate on the screen :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newx = distance * Math.cos(direction) + x
newy = distance * Math.sin(direction) + y
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I thought they'd used cos and sin. Never understood either quite that well, though. Suppose I should look up trig functions.

Comment: Remember 'sohcahtoa' from high school? :)

Answer (score 0):

By calculating the sine and cosine of the angle, you can get the point one unit away from the origin at the given rotation.  Just multiply the coordinates by whatever distance you need.  Cosine corresponds to X and sine corresponds to Y.

In other words:

- Decide on the angle.
- Calculate X by getting the cosine of the angle.
- Calculate Y by getting the sine of the angle.
- Multiply X and Y by the distance.
- Offset X and Y by your "source" point.

Comment: sine corresponds to Y and cosine corresponds to X

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. If you could add some pseudo code I'd say it will be complete :)

Comment: @Senthil I would, but I don't know anything about HTML5 (and I don't want to post something I don't understand myself).